# How to specify the root folder to deploy an app using the Cloud SDK?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-shell

I'm using "Google App Engine" from GCP to host a static website. I already created the website files (HTML, JS) and yaml using Visual Studio Code. I have the folder with those files stored locally in my local computer.

I downloaded the Cloud SDK Shell for Windows. I logged in to my account, and selected the project. According to videos and tutorials, I need to deploy the app using "gcloud app deploy".

However I got an error saying that an "app.yaml" file is required to deploy this directory...

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website#before_you_begin

I'm also trying to follow the steps contained in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlcO7nfQzSg

How do I specify the root folder where I have my "app.yaml" file?

Thanks in advance!!

I already tried with many commands and unfortunately none of them have worked

Answer (score 5):

The particular case in which `gcloud app deploy` works without additional arguments is for single-service applications only and only if the command is executed in the directory in which the service's `app.yaml` configuration file exists (and has that exact name, can't use a different name).

For other cases deployables can/must be specified. From [`gcloud app deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> gcloud app deploy [DEPLOYABLES …] [--bucket=BUCKET] [--image-url=IMAGE_URL] [--no-promote] [--no-stop-previous-version]
> ```
>
> [--version=VERSION, -v VERSION] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> This command is used to deploy both code and configuration to the App
>   Engine server. As an input it takes one or more `DEPLOYABLES` that
>   should be uploaded. A `DEPLOYABLE` can be a service's .yaml file or a
>   configuration's .yaml file (for more information about configuration
>   files specific to your App Engine environment, refer to
>   https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/configuration-files
>   or
>   https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuration-files).
>   Note, for Java Standard apps, you must add the path to the
>   `appengine-web.xml` file inside the WEB-INF directory. gcloud app
>   deploy skips files specified in the .gcloudignore file (see `gcloud
>   topic gcloudignore` for more information).

So apart from running the command with no arguments in the directory in which your `app.yaml` exists is to specify the `app.yaml` (with a full or relative path if needed) as a deployable:

```
gcloud app deploy path/to/your/app.yaml
```

IMHO doing this is a good habit - specifying deployables is more reliable and is the only way to deploy apps with multiple services or using routing via a `dispatch.yaml` file.

Answer (score 2):

`gcloud app deploy` will look at the current directory first for `app.yaml`.   Generally you will change to the directory with app.yaml and your other files before deploying