# What am i doing wrong here? Anytime i execute this line it directs to one directory

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

Anytime i try executing "gcloud app deploy", below is what i get. I just don't know why.

> C:\Users\charl\Desktop\Apps\webTest\webTest>gcloud app deploy ERROR:
>   An app.yaml (or appengine-web.xml) file is required to deploy this
>   directory as an App Engine application. Create an app.yaml file using
>   the directions at
>   https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
>   (App Engine Flexible Environment) or
>   https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref
>   (App Engine Standard Environment) under the tab for your language.
>   ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) [C:\Users\charl] could not be identified as
>   a valid source directory or file.

Comment: Try specifying the deployable instead of relying on auto-detection, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53955087/4495081

Answer (score 2):

App Engine comes in two flavors: the classic "App Engine Standard" and the newer "App Engine Flex(ible)".

Both require some configuration in order for the App Engine service to understand how you wish to run your app. In many instances, this configuration is with a file called `app.yaml`. For App Engine Standard for Java, the file is called `appengine-web.xml`. You'll need to create one of these two files for your app before you can deploy it.

The error message you received is helpful. It provides you with links to help you create the file you will need for a successful deployment.